# Getting the entire body element of an html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

https://www.apple.com/covid19/mobility

```
source=requests.get("https://www.apple.com/covid19/mobility")
soup=BeautifulSoup(source.text,"lxml")
```

I'm currently trying to get the url contained in the All Data CSV button which can be found by inspecting element. The `requests.get` doesn't seem to return the full body and all the  elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following API which returns data in `json()` format.

> https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/current/v1/index.json

Now to get the url use key values

**Code**:

```
url='https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/current/v1/index.json'
data=requests.get(url).json()
print("https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com"+data['basePath'] +data['regions']['en-us']['csvPath'])
```

**Output**:

```
https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2006HotfixDev17/v1/en-us/applemobilitytrends-2020-04-25.csv
```

---

To get csv data in json format try this API

```
url='https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2006HotfixDev17/v1/en-us/applemobilitytrends.json'
data=requests.get(url).json()
print(data)
```